# Android - org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to sort scores coming from a JSONArray and output only the top 10. Here is my code.

```
try {
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


List<String> jsonValues = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
   jsonValues.add(jArray.getString(i));
Collections.sort(jsonValues);
JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonValues);


for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    JSONObject jObject;
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obj  = (JSONObject) parser.parse((String) sortedJsonArray.get(i));

        Score score =new Score();
        score.setId(obj.getInt("Id"));
        score.setPlayerId(obj.getInt("PlayerId"));
        score.setHiScore(obj.getInt("HiScore"));
        tempList.add(score);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I wanted to parse the sortedJsonArray into JSONObject that's why I used org.json.simple.JSONObject, but It says it cannot be cast to JSONObject. I tried using org.json.simple.JSONObject datatype for ***obj*** but I got this error

```
The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject
```

I am retrieving data from a web server

```
List<Score> tempList = new ArrayList<Score>();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(EndPoint+"/Scores");
String result="";
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = client.execute(getRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity!=null){
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        StreamConverter sc= new StreamConverter();
        result= StreamConverter.convertStreamToString(instream);
        instream.close();
    }
```

**EDIT**

I realized that I could just parse JSONArray to string using (String) and not use JSONParse. -____-

```
jObject =  new JSONObject((String) sortedJsonArray.get(i));
```

Comment: pls post json here

Comment: Try this        JSONObject obj  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sortedJsonArray.get(i));

Comment: Khizar Hayat I have tried that, it says that sortedJsonArray is an Object, and  JSONParser accepts String.

Comment: can you post your import statements. it seems you are using a different library http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html. is the JSONOBject. But your have org.json.simple.JSONObect. check your json and the import statements on android

Answer (score 0):

Try this for parsing :

```
  try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS).equals("true")) {

                preDefineAlertList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> mapNew = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                 //   Log.d("obj", obj.toString());


                    alert_message = obj.getString(Constants.Params.MESSAGE);
                    id = obj.getString(Constants.Params.ID);



                    mapNew.put("message", message);
                    mapNew.put("id",id);


                   // Log.d("mapNew", mapNew.toString());
                    preDefinetList.add(mapNew);

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the JSONObject of a library which uses Default JSONObject and does some manipulations to it.
You are using the JSONObject of that library from the package of simple.Jsonobject and you are trying to compare it to default json.Jsonobject .
Try yo see what exactly you are doing to cause it . It will help you not just in this case but in future as well.